# Show that there is a continuous function $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ with $g(x)=f(x)$ for every $x\in C$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $C$ be closed set in $\Bbb R$ and let $f:C\to \Bbb R$ be continuous.

Show that there is a continuous function $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ with $g(x)=f(x)$ for every $x\in C$.

I am unable to view how to construct $g$ from $f$.

Please give some hints.

Comment: Think about a function which extends what happens on the boundary of $C$.

Comment: This is a direct consequence of Tietze's extension theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem

Comment: Since $C$ is closed then the complement is open in $\mathbb{R}$ so it is a countable union of intervals. I think (perhaps incorrectly) you use this to extend the function linearly inside each interval.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem).